# :checked is selecting select inputs as well

Tags: jquery

I have a form that has select inputs as well as checkboxes.  The following selector:

```
$(':checked')
```

selected both, so I had to use:

```
$(':checkbox:checked')
```

to only select the checkboxes that were checked.

Q: Did I find a bug in jQuery, or is it just my understanding?

Comment: It's worth noting that using `$(':checkbox')` *implies* the universal selector `*`, effectively giving `$('*:checkbox')`, so jQuery's checking *every* element on the page to see if it's of the `type="checkbox"`. Try to reduce the workload with `$('input:checkbox')` :) Reference: [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector).

Comment: I think we need to see some HTML, `:checked` shouldn't select select options: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/2sxAC/

Comment: @mu is too short ... your comment is not accurate it depends on the browser.  FF3.6 will report differently than IE 8.

Comment: Thanks David.  For production, I've made it: $('#myID input:checkbox:checked')

Comment: @John: Interesting. I checked with WebKit and it doesn't select select options, Firefox 4 does, and I have no idea what IE does. I'd probably call that a Firefox bug. The jQuery docs even say that ":checked" is for checkboxes and radio buttons only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

technically select elements, radio buttons, and checkboxes have a checked state, so it's not a bug.

[input-checked](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-checked)

---

from jQuerys documentation `:checked` should not work for `select` elements so you might be right... testing in jsfiddle

> The :checked selector works for checkboxes and radio buttons. For select elements, use the :selected selector.

---

From this test: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/zAC54/

I'm not seeing the results that you're seeing...

Have you added a `checked` property to the `select` inputs through code?

Answer (score 0):

`:checked` is not what you want if you just want to check for checkboxes

```
$("input:checked") //selector for checked radio buttons and checkboxes
$("input:radio:checked") //selector for checked radio buttons
$("input:checkbox:checked") //selector for checked checkboxes
```

Finally it is not a good idea for performance reasons to use class selectors and other special selectors by themselves with out a tagname.  The reason for this is jQuery will run though all the dom elements looking for that class or selector.. If you apply a tag name jquery will attempt to use getElementsByTagName first then iterate through only those elements with the following tag name.  It is quicker and more efficient.